# Calling actionscript function from JS

Tags: javascript, html, flash, actionscript

I would appreciate any help with this issue.

I am trying to execute an AS function when a certain link is clicked but I cannot get it working.  I am running the code as follows:

In my object constructor, I have the following line:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("methodName",methodName);
```

and my function is defined (outside the constructor) as follows:

```
function methodName()
        {
//functioncode here
        }
```

Inside my html file, the javascript code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function callExternalInterface() {
    thisMovie("swf").methodName();
}
function thisMovie(movieName) {
    if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
        return window[movieName]
    }
    else {
        return document[movieName]
    }
}
    </script>
```

Code for the button to call the above function:

```
<input type="button" onclick="callExternalInterface()" value="Call ExternalInterface" />
```

The flash object is embedded the following way:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="655" height="324" align="middle" id="swf" name="swf">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false">
    <param name="movie" value="flash1.swf">
    <param name="menu" value="false">
    <param name="quality" value="best">
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#f3f3f3">  
    <embed src="flash1.swf" menu="false" quality="best" bgcolor="#f3f3f3" width="655" height="324" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="always" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" id="swf" name="swf">
    </object>
```

According to the Firebug console, when I click on the button, I get the following error:

> thisMovie("swf").methodName is not a function

It looks like it's a javascript error that's not recognizing the function.  I got most of the code from this site,  I would appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Comment: wheres the code for the javascript function callExternalInterface() ?

Comment: oops, sorry, was a bad paste of code.  added it in there.

Comment: have you tried different browsers?

Comment: Sometimes that's a timing problem when you try to call the function before the Flash has initialized. However, it seems unlikely in this particular case. At the time you press the button, the Flash should be loaded. What does `console.log(thisMovie("swf"))` say?

Comment: Pumbaa im not entirely sure, how do I get that log? (the error message in my original post was posted from the Firebug Console)

Comment: Katherine - how confident are you that the Flash/AS part of this is working properly? For example - not knowing more about your code/app - it's possible that the Flash object that contains the "methodName" function has been garbage collected by the time you attempt to call it. Or, perhaps it's never instantiated in the first place? I'm not suggesting that's the case, but it's possible, unless you're confident that *that* part of the code is solid. It certainly would explain the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Katherine - two more dumb questions. First, are you using AS3 or AS2 for your Flash app? (I ask because in AS2 - the parameters for ExternalInterface.addCallback() are different...). Second - are you importing flash.external.ExternalInterface at the top of your code? (I know, that's a *really* dumb question, but I don't know how comfortable with Flash you are...)

Answer (score 1):

Check a running sample here http://www.redcodelabs.com/2012/04/calling-actionscript-method-from-javascript/

Here is some code from the post

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.text.TextFieldType;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;

    public class ExternalInterfaceExample extends Sprite {
        private var input:TextField;
        private var output:TextField;
        private var sendBtn:Sprite;

        public function ExternalInterfaceExample() {
            input = new TextField();
            input.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
            input.background = true;
            input.border = true;
            input.width = 350;
            input.height = 18;
            addChild(input);

            sendBtn = new Sprite();
            sendBtn.mouseEnabled = true;
            sendBtn.x = input.width + 10;
            sendBtn.graphics.beginFill(0xCCCCCC);
            sendBtn.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 80, 18, 10, 10);
            sendBtn.graphics.endFill();
            sendBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
            addChild(sendBtn);

            output = new TextField();
            output.y = 25;
            output.width = 450;
            output.height = 325;
            output.multiline = true;
            output.wordWrap = true;
            output.border = true;
            output.text = "Initializing...\n";
            addChild(output);

            if (ExternalInterface.available) {
                try {
                    output.appendText("Adding callback...\n");
                    ExternalInterface.addCallback("sendToActionScript", receivedFromJavaScript);
                    if (checkJavaScriptReady()) {
                        output.appendText("JavaScript is ready.\n");
                    } else {
                        output.appendText("JavaScript is not ready, creating timer.\n");
                        var readyTimer:Timer = new Timer(100, 0);
                        readyTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
                        readyTimer.start();
                    }
                } catch (error:SecurityError) {
                    output.appendText("A SecurityError occurred: " + error.message + "\n");
                } catch (error:Error) {
                    output.appendText("An Error occurred: " + error.message + "\n");
                }
            } else {
                output.appendText("External interface is not available for this container.");
            }
        }
        private function receivedFromJavaScript(value:String):void {
            output.appendText("JavaScript says: " + value + "\n");
        }
        private function checkJavaScriptReady():Boolean {
            var isReady:Boolean = ExternalInterface.call("isReady");
            return isReady;
        }
        private function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void {
            output.appendText("Checking JavaScript status...\n");
            var isReady:Boolean = checkJavaScriptReady();
            if (isReady) {
                output.appendText("JavaScript is ready.\n");
                Timer(event.target).stop();
            }
        }
        private function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
            if (ExternalInterface.available) {
                ExternalInterface.call("sendToJavaScript", input.text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AND the html / JS

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>ExternalInterfaceExample</title>
 <script language="JavaScript">
     var jsReady = false;
     function isReady() {
         return jsReady;
     }
     function pageInit() {
         jsReady = true;
         document.forms["form1"].output.value += "\n" + "JavaScript is ready.\n";
     }
     function thisMovie(movieName) {
         if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
             return window[movieName];
         } else {
             return document[movieName];
         }
     }
     function sendToActionScript(value) {
         thisMovie("ExternalInterfaceExample").sendToActionScript(value);
     }
     function sendToJavaScript(value) {
         document.forms["form1"].output.value += "ActionScript says: " + value + "\n";
     }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="pageInit();">

     <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
             id="ExternalInterfaceExample" width="500" height="375"
             codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab">
         <param name="movie" value="ExternalInterfaceExample.swf" />
         <param name="quality" value="high" />
         <param name="bgcolor" value="#869ca7" />
         <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
         <embed src="ExternalInterfaceExample.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#869ca7"
             width="500" height="375" name="ExternalInterfaceExample" align="middle"
             play="true" loop="false" quality="high" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
             type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
             pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
         </embed>
     </object>

     <form name="form1" onsubmit="return false;">
         <input type="text" name="input" value="" />
         <input type="button" value="Send" onclick="sendToActionScript(this.form.input.value);" /><br />
         <textarea cols="60" rows="20" name="output" readonly="true">Initializing...</textarea>
     </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The question issue description that you have provided in incomplete to arrive on any conclusion why you are facing issue.

Here a working test code that I created - using the part of code that you have provided -

JavaScript Function in Header Tag of HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function callExternalInterface() {
         thisMovie("swf").methodName();
      }

      function thisMovie(movieName) {
        if(navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
           return window[movieName]
        } else {
           return document[movieName]
        }
       }
</script>
```

Flash Object Embedded in Following way:

```
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
        <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" id="swf" width="550" height="400" align="middle">
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="Always" />
            <param name="movie" value="AS3-JS.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
            <embed src="AS3-JS.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="550" height="400" swLiveConnect=true id="swf" name="swf" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="Always" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
```

And AS Class File

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

public class Main extends MovieClip {


    public function Main() 
    {
        // constructor code
        ExternalInterface.addCallback("methodName",methodName);
    }

    private function methodName():void
    {
        msg_txt.htmlText = "Called"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: didn't work at all ... getting cann't read property methodName of undefined